# Chartjs: Multiple data values for the same label

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I'm trying to build a chart that looks like this ...

[Chart bar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcjxt.png)

However I am not able to use multiple data values for the same label. Does anyone have any ideas? I'm using chart.js

I would like the code to look something like this...

```
labels: ['category 1, 'category 2'],
datasets: [
      {
        // values for category one
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: '#8e5ea2',
        data: [111, 222, 333]
      }, {
        // values for category two
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: '#3e95cd',
        data: [111, 222, 333]
      }
    ]
```

However, chart.js takes each data item for each label created. I would like to have multiple date items for just one label

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work but you can try to specify the data as an object and then in the first dataset put all the x values to the first label and in the second dataset put all the x values to the second label.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/data-structures

Comment: This way it doesn't really work, I'll look at the content you sent, and try this way... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    labels: ['category 1, 'category 2'],
datasets: [
      {
        // values for category one
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: '#8e5ea2',
        data: [111, 222, 333],
        stack: 'Stack 1'
      }, {
        // values for category two
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: '#3e95cd',
        data: [111, 222, 333],
        stack: 'Stack 1'## Heading ##
      }
    ]
```